# How to select linq entities?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entities

Database name 1: `BOOK`, table name: `BookInformation` (BookID(PK),BookName))

```
BookID        BookName                       
---------------------
  19          A   
  25          T    
  56          F    
  45          H
  77          K
  53          M
  76          YT
```

I want to get the ID values ​​in the table.So I write this linq entities query.But this query error.

```
   var query= from a in Book.BookInformation.AsEnumerable.Select(a=>a.BookID).ToList();
```

How to write get the ID values?

Comment: Why remove.AsEnumerable? I want to select Id this table.

Comment: So, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I want to get the ıd value from the table.ı wrote this query but it is wrong. How to select this table ıd use entities?

Comment: @GertArnold book is databasename and bookinformation tablename.

Comment: Maybe there can be false solutions My write AsEnumerable query.maybe it wont be. This asenumerable solutions is wrong.How can ı correctly query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var idList= Book.BookInformation.Select(a=>a.BookID).ToList();
```